# JAXB: Bind element type xs:string to an Enum

Tags: java, xml, enums, jaxb

My vendor has provided me with an `XSD` that has an element defined as a `String`.  However in his spec, he indicates that this string can only have 1 of 3 values:

Ex:

```
<xs:complexType name="MitigationStatus">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      This represents a list of mitigation statuses.  Can be OPEN, CLOSED, INVALID 
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="status" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I would like to add something to my bindings file such that when I unmarshal my `XML`, the status is not a `String` but rather an `Enum`.

All the docs I have found seem to indicate that the `XSD` requires the `String` to be of an `enum` type.

Is there a way to bind the string to an `Enum` type even if the `XSD` is not an `enum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define this restriction in the XML schema slightly modified with the changes indicated below and generate your Java classes from it.

```
 <xs:simpleType name="StatusType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:enumeration value="OPEN"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="CLOSED"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="INVALID"/>
   </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>

...
  <xs:element name="status" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="StatusType"/>
...
```

This will result in an enum class StatusType. In XML, everything is string anyway, so it remains as is.

If you really want to do this via a bindings file, you can use something like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='MitigationStatus']">
  <jaxb:bindings node="./xsd:element[@name='status']">
    <jaxb:property>
      <jaxb:baseType>
        <jaxb:javaType name="StatusImpl"
                       parseMethod="StatusImpl.parseStringToEnum"
                       printMethod="StatusImpl.printEnumToString"/>
      </jaxb:baseType>
    </jaxb:property>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Assuming an enum StatusType, class StatusImpl is simply

```
public class StatusImpl {
    public static StatusType parseStringToEnum( String value ){
        return StatusType.valueOf( value );
    }
    public static String printEnumToString( StatusType impl ){
        return impl.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what problem you are having, but the following works fine. As you can see, there's no XSD, just manually coded JAXB classes.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<Path>\r\n" +
                     "  <Direction>North</Direction>\r\n" +
                     "  <Direction>North</Direction>\r\n" +
                     "  <Direction>East</Direction>\r\n" +
                     "  <Direction>South</Direction>\r\n" +
                     "</Path>";
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Path.class);
        Path path = (Path)jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        for (Direction dir : path.directions)
            System.out.println(dir);
    }
}
@XmlEnum
enum Direction {
    @XmlEnumValue("North") NORTH,
    @XmlEnumValue("South") SOUTH,
    @XmlEnumValue("East")  EAST,
    @XmlEnumValue("West")  WEST
}
@XmlRootElement(name = "Path")
class Path {
    @XmlElement(name = "Direction")
    List<Direction> directions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

*Output*

```
NORTH
NORTH
EAST
SOUTH
```

Comment: Answering while you write "I don't know what problem you are having" sounds kind of funny. Also, please note that OP explicitly requested an addition to a bindings file.